# Athena sql date_diff

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Running athena sql query

```
select date_diff('day' ,checkout_date::date, book_date::date) from users.
```

book_date and checkout_date are all timestamp.Got an error:

> Error running query: function date_diff(unknown, date, date) does not exist ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Checked presto documentation:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

date_diff(unit, timestamp1, timestamp2) → bigint

```
Returns timestamp2 - timestamp1 expressed in terms of unit.
```

Comment: Can you provide sample checkout_date and book_date values. also what is the data type of the column. If it is just date format , format it to timestamp and try.

Answer (score 1):

Sample of function is given, probably you need to cast columns in timestamp

[image: Function e.g]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast the timestamps at all - as you have noted in the documentation, the function expects 2 timestamps (or dates) after the varchar which denotes the time unit.

So

```
select date_diff('day', checkout_date, book_date) from users;
```

should be fine.